# Adjective Complements

Tags: adjectives

Could you please tell me the differences between adjective + to inf and adj + preposition + Ving .For example,

I am happy to be here vs I am happy with being here

I am afraid to be late vs I am afraid of being late

Answer (score 2):

Provided the preposition is selected by the adjective, I don't think there is a difference.  There is an analysis under which the preposition is underlyingly present in both versions, but has to be deleted before the infinitive, or, in general, before either a for-to nominalization or a "that"-clause:

```
I am happy with (my) being here. [POSS-ing complement]  
I am happy (with) (for me) to be here. [for-to complement]  
I am happy (with) that I am here. [that-clause complement]
```

Some verbs present the same paradigm:

```
He decided on (his) buying the boat.  [POSS-ing complement]  
He decided (on) (for him) to buy the boat. [for-to complement]  
He decided (on) that he would buy the boat. [that-clause complement]
```

In case the NP which is the nominalized sentence is pronominalized with a suitable antecedent, the preposition need not be deleted, so it can pop back up:

```
I am here, and I am happy with that (= me being here).  
She wanted him to buy the boat, and he finally decided on  
  that (= that he would buy the boat).
```

Answer (score 0):

Good question; I too have wondered the same.

I suppose the foremost difference is that "I am happy **to be here**" contains an infinitive phrase, whereas "I am happy **with being here**" contains a prepositional phrase.

As to a deeper distinction between the two, I suppose that the first example indicates a relationship between the *adjective* and an *infinitive* for a specific verb (or its gerund form) related *to the subject*:

1) e.g. "I am happy *to serve* dinner for you" as compared to "I am happy *with serving* dinner to the guests."

However, this creates a subtly between the type of verb that is presented by the infinite:

2) e.g "I am happy *to wash* the plates" as compared to "I am happy *with being washing* the plates," where the latter is an obvious nonsense statement, since it has both "being" and "washing".

So the second construction, when using only "to be", indicates a relationship between the adjective and a state of being designated by the prepositional phrase. So I suppose using "to be" is a specific subclass of the larger form of using gerund as opposed to using its infinitive. Hope this helps.